# How to add bookmark in leaves?

Tags: iphone, ios, bookmarks

I am using [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves) for a pdf reader app ..

I had set page number, UIScreen brightness etc. but I stuck here....

each page have BOOL bookmark value , if the page is bookmarked bookmarked image should shown in bookmark button , it can remove bookmark from bookmarked page ......

How can I add page as **bookmark** and display added bookmarks ?

thanks ....

Comment: what you exact want..  you want to save bookmarks in new button Clicked....

Comment: yes i want to add bookmark in each page if yes then bookmark image blue and if not bookmark then black bookmark image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use NSUSSER Default. Save that bookmark value into NSUSERDEfault and Then set the Blue image.

And check weather this value is present into NSUSerDefault if not then set the Black image. It's so easy...

Try this code

Create Defulat like this....

```
NSUserDefaults * BookMarkDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Adding Value into Bookmanrk use this code once added that value then Set the blue image where you want to set.

```
[BookMarkDefault setObject:YoursavedData forKey:@"YourKey"];
 imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"];
```

dont forget to Synchronize the Default...

```
[BoomMarkDefault Synchronize];
```

if you want to get that data from NSUSerDefault check out this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[BookMarkDefault objectForKey:@"YourKey"]);
```

Try this code....